# How can I formulate price elasticity of demand equation when I want to add cross price elasticity?

Tags: econometrics, elasticity, cross-price-elasticity

[image]I am trying to calculate the price elasticity of demand for a product where I used the equation

log(volume) = elasticity * log(price) + seasonality dummies + trend index + CPI

Here CPI is the consumer price index, formula of CPI = (sum - price)/(price *n )] ,

price = price of the product ,sum = sum of all other product ,n = number of all other product

How can I add cross elasticity to the equation? Or have CPI covered it

Comment: This appears to be time-series data. Are all your variables, particularly volume, price, CPI stationary? Or are you assuming cointegration? Also what is trend index? Is it a variable for deterministic trend?

Comment: No the price and volume are not stationary, So basically I am calculating elasticity using linear regression, for which I have price and volume values monthly data for 3 years and where the trend index is just integers from 1 to 36 for say Jan 18 to dec 20, and I am also using  dummy variables for all months for seasonality.

Comment: In that case there is a problem in this regression because your regressors are non-stationary. The time index term would take care of the non-stationarity of the dependent variable (assuming it has only deterministic trend) but regressors are still a problem.

Comment: for cross-elasticity you need prices of other specific good as well, CPI is not enough

Comment: I have updated the question, where you can see my modeling dataset for one product, so for trend and seasonality, I have added trend index and dummy variables for months. I wanted to find a better way to include the cross-price elasticity in the equation. Also I wanted to know if there's a better way than regression if regressors are still a problem? @csilvia